# Need help understanding preg_match regular expression

Tags: php, regex

A regular expression in preg_match is given as `/server\-([^\-\.\d]+)(\d+)/`. Can someone help me understand what this means? I see that the string starts with `server-` but I dont get `([^\-\.\d]+)(\d+)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the explanation:

```
# server\-([^\-\.\d]+)(\d+)
# 
# Match the characters “server” literally «server»
# Match the character “-” literally «\-»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^\-\.\d]+)»
#    Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^\-\.\d]+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
#       A - character «\-»
#       A . character «\.»
#       A single digit 0..9 «\d»
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\d+)»
#    Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

You can use programs such as [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) if you intend to work with regexes and are willing to spend some funds.

You can also use [this free web based explanation utility](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl).

Comment: How is `([^\-\.\d]+)` Match a single character `NOT` present? I thought it was to match `\-, \. and digits`

Comment: This is because the first characters inside the `[]` brackets is `^`. This characters means _match all characters except those specified inside the brackets_.

Answer (score 2):

`[ ]` -> Match anything inside the square brackets for ONE character position once and only once, for example, [12] means match the target to 1 and if that does not match then match the target to 2 while [0123456789] means match to any character in the range 0 to 9.

`-`   ->  The - (dash) inside square brackets is the 'range separator' and allows us to define a range, in our example above of [0123456789] we could rewrite it as [0-9].

You can define more than one range inside a list, for example, [0-9A-C] means check for 0 to 9 and A to C (but not a to c).

NOTE: To test for - inside brackets (as a literal) it must come first or last, that is, [-0-9] will test for - and 0 to 9.

`^` -> The ^ (circumflex or caret) inside square brackets negates the expression (we will see an alternate use for the circumflex/caret outside square brackets later), for example, [^Ff] means anything except upper or lower case F and [^a-z] means everything except lower case a to z.

You can check more explanations about it in the source I got this information: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

And if u want to test, u can try this one: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1):

`^` means *not one of the following characters inside the brackets*

`\-` `\.` are the `-` and `.` characters

`\d` is a number

`[^\-\.\d]+` means on of more of the characters inside the bracket, so *one or more* of anything not a `-`, `.` or a number.

`(\d+)` one or more number

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation given by the perl module `YAPE::Regex::Explain`

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:server\-([^\-\.\d]+)(\d+))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  server                   'server'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \-                       '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\-\.\d]+               any character except: '\-', '\.', digits
                             (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Woah, we have a package that explains regexes??